# CKEditor cannot get current instance from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, ckeditor

CKEditor 4 or above

I have form > textarea with CKEditor enabled and functioning.

I have iframe in modal dialog and inside iframe is button with insert_media() javascript function.

```
function insert_media( element ) {
    // get element html decode
    element = htmlspecialchars_decode( element, 'ENT_QUOTES' );
    // htmlspecialchars_decode is external function.

    // CKEditor insert element ---------------------------------------------
    // use .insertElement()
    var CKEDITOR = window.parent.CKEDITOR;
    var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(element);

    // body_value is name of textarea
    // this code only works with specific textarea NOT current active textarea
    //CKEDITOR.instances.body_value.insertElement(element);

    var current_instance_ckeditor = window.parent.test_current();
    // CKEditor insert element ---------------------------------------------

    // close modal dialog at parent window
    window.parent.close_dialog();

    // done
    return false;
}// insert_media
```

and this is javascript in main page html

```
function close_dialog() {
    $('#media-modal').modal('hide');
}// close_dialog


function test_current() {
    console.log( CKEDITOR.currentInstance.name );
}
```

The problem is i **cannot get current active CKEditor** to insert element with insertElement command.

CKEDITOR.currentInstance is undefined or null

window.parent.CKEDITOR.currentInstance is undefined or null

How to **get current active CKEditor** from iframe?

---

file for test: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/420060/test-ckeditor-zip.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `CKEDITOR.currentInstance` is `null/undefined`, then none editor instance is active. It means that you moved focus out of editor to the place which is not recognised as its part.

However, if you're using CKEditor's dialogs (do you?) editor instance should always be active, when this dialog is opened for it. If this is your case, then you need to provide us a working example, because it's hard to guess what can be wrong.

Second option is that you don't use CKEditor's dialogs and then you have to take care of registering that iframe to the CKEditor's [focusManager](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.focusManager), although this is tricky so you rather should not use 3rd party's dialogs with CKEditor.

**Edit** The `test_current` function works fine when I click "test" button, but editor has to be focused. But after 200ms from the moment you click button editor will be blurred and you won't be able to get it from `currentInstance`. To avoid blurring editor when clicking button you need to register it in `focusManagers` (of both editors if it will be used with both).

Comment: I use bootstrap dialog not CKEditor's dialog.
This is my files. http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/420060/test-ckeditor-zip.html

the problem is in test2.html inside zip file.

Comment: Have you tried to use focusManager? Basically, you need to call `editor.focusManager.add( yourFocusableElement )`. However, as I wrote - this is tricky since you use iframes. Regarding your upload - please create simplified sample on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have 2 editor, so i don't know what 'editor.' is?
i don't see any focusManager example on net, so i don't know how to use.

i cannot create sample on jsfiddle because it use 2 html files and jsfiddle does not support something like modal dialog with iframe page in it.

Comment: I updated my answer. But you should still consider using CKEditor's dialogs and buttons if you're not familiar with focus handling, because it will be hard for you to make it work correctly.

Comment: Dear Reinmar, i have figure out how to make it work in the answer below.   
now everyone can work with their dialog without CKE's dialogs.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this

```
    var ck_instance_name = false;
    for ( var ck_instance in CKEDITOR.instances ){
        if (CKEDITOR.instances[ck_instance].focusManager.hasFocus){
            ck_instance_name = ck_instance;
            return ck_instance_name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor is null/undefined as Reinmar said.

Now i can find the way to work with current instance even if you clicked outside CKEditor.

Here is sample files for test.
http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/448409/test-ckeditor-zip.html

What i do is ...

1. Add global variable for current instance in javascript (in html)
2. On click button for open modal dialog, get current instance and set to global variable in choice 1.
3. On click insert button in iframe in modal dialog, get window.parent.current_instance variable and use as texteditor id. (`var parent_cke_current_id = window.parent.current_instance_id;`)
4. Now do what ever you want with clicked CKEditor instance. for example (`CKEDITOR.instances[parent_cke_current_id].insertElement(element);`)

Thank you Reinmar.